# Как сделать автоматический запуск и отключение MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript

Мой код добавляет и удаляет класс _disabled, если нет myobserver.disconnect(). Но как только я добавляю в код myobserver.disconnect(), то класс _disabled уже не добавляется, потому-что observer остановлен. Как сделать так, что-бы MutationObserver запускался при обнаружении .myclass снова?

```
new MutationObserver((mutations, myobserver) => {
    const Node = document.querySelector('.myclass');
  if (Node.matches('.myclass')){
  document.querySelector('.btn.red').classList.remove('_disabled');
   } else {
   document.querySelector('.btn.red').classList.add('_disabled');
    myobserver.disconnect() }
  }).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

Comment: в чем смысл этого MutationObserver?

Comment: Удалить или добавить класс в зависимости есть ли элемент на странице или нет. Код работает, Но как запустить его снова. Если убрать  .disconnect() Так он постоянно работает, а хотелось бы его останавливать и запускать когда элемент появится свнова.

Comment: а зачем вызывать disconnect, если ты хочешь чтобы код работал постоянно?

Comment: Я не хочу что-бы он работал постоянно. Я хочу что-бы он отключался и включался. Появился элемент, удалился класс и observer отключился. Опять появляется элемент .myclass и observer снова включается,  Или так невозможно сделать?

Comment: если ты "отключишь" обсервер, кто будет следит за появлением нужного элемента чтобы снова включить обсервер?

Comment: Да, действительно, об этом я не подумал))